# sybase IQ network client install

Tags: linux, sybase, sap-iq

Can any please please help me out in installing the SYBASE IQ network client on hadoop linux server as I would require it to connect to the SYBASE IQ database.
I am not able to find the exact procedure to install the client on linux.
If possible please share the doc with the download links.

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can download free IQ editions from http://scn.sap.com/community/iq (but usage restrictions may apply).